# App for Android which allows users to write a few sentences as diary

Tags: android

My cell phone is running Android.  I am looking for an application for my cell phone.

I like writing a diary, but my diary book only has a few fresh pages left and I don't want to buy a new one.

I want to write a diary entry every day in the app so that I can easily read and search for some particular diary entries.

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: a diary = a note with dates as titles right? if so i could offer up a few good note taking apps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can recommend [Diary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sleepwalkers.diary) by DroidVeda LLP.

Many Android diaries focus on "cute", whereas DroidVeda's Diary focuses on *content* and ease of use.

It meets your requirements of being able to easily read and search for particular diary entries.

Here are the key features, from the Play Store description:

> 1. Simple to use
> 2. Password protected
> 3. Date-wise display of pages
> 4. Swipe to navigate between pages
> 5. Export to PDF (Currently supports English only)
> 6. Attach Photos
> 7. Take picture from Camera and attach
> 8. Autosave
> 9. Quick search
> 10. List all entries
> 11. Themes
> 12. Backup & Restore
> 13. Go to a Date (Tap on Page header to jump to a Date)
> 14. Fonts
> 15. Free hand drawing

One of the best features is the freehand draw mode where you can make quick sketches of your emotions, thoughts, or ideas.

The auto-save feature is very convenient: it automatically saves all your entries for you.

Here is what the entry screen looks like.  It is nice and simple:

[image: Diary UI]

Give it a try... you'll probably like it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you are facing is that you say you are looking for an Android **Diary** but on most mobile phones the *Diary* is actually a **Scheduling** and **Reminders** App.

If you are looking for an analogue of a paper diary that you record what happened to you today and your thoughts of the day then you need to look for what is called ***Blogging*** or ***Journalling*** software.  There is lots of it out there.

Blogging software takes what you write and posts it to an on-line "Blog" this has the following features:

- Saved to the net so not lost if you change/lose your phone
- Can usually include things like photos as well
- Is visible to the whole on-line world ***this is probably the bit that you would not like**

But there are some Blogging/Journalling services, and applications that work with them, that allow you to have a private Blog which only you can see, *(plus of course the FBI, CIA & several others but that is probably the case if it is just on your phone or in a paper diary).*

So can I suggest that you look for a Blogging **Service** that is available in your location, meets your budget and has any privacy features you desire and then look for an App that works with **that** service, *many such services have a recommended App*.

Possible services:

- [Penzu](http://penzu.com/) - Free Journalling via browser $20pa for Pro which has iPhone, iPad & Android Apps
- [Tumblr](http://www.tumblr.com/) - Offers blogging with the option of Private entries/blogs as do [Wordpress](http://wordpress.com/), [Livejournal](http://www.livejournal.com/), [Squarespace](http://squarespace.com/)
- You **could** host your own blog on the web in a private server area, or on your own server, that you simply don't give access to anybody else - either would be better for privacy but require more effort on your part.
- You could even simply have a **not shared** area in your [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com/) that you simply keep entries in plain text files, (say one per month with a name like 2015_Nov.txt), and use any text editor to view and update them from any platform.

Comment: Thank you for the help, Steve Barnes. I am reading your answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you would like an app where you can add an update everyday and search for an update, the [Journey](https://journey.cloud/) app came to my mind. I have had it with me and made use of it but now I just create a Google Doc for each day as that is a better fit for my life.